# Actionscript 3 - From Full_Screen to full_screen_interactive

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In AS3 I've made a fullscreen button that toggles from Fullscreen to normal.
I added a text editor and I've learned that it'll only work with Full_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE.
When I click on a button to open the text editor, I made a functions that checks whether it's Fullscreen or normal. My problem is if it's in fullscreen mode, how I can switch from FULL_SCREEN mode to Full_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE.

```
if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN) {  
  stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
}
```

This doesn't work, I also tried going to normal mode as a bridge then to interactive, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you placing that code?

In "normal" Flash applications, you can only switch to full screen modes after user interaction (click/keyboard). AIR doesn't present this restriction.

iirc, the interactive mode only works for non-AIR applications as of 11.3, so make sure that you're targeting a recent version of Flash Player.

Comment: Another thing you could try is to add something like     `stage.addEventListener('fullScreen', goInteractive);` and then toogle to interactive mode from there, but I'm not sure if it will work forn non-AIR applications.

Comment: Yes, In solved that problem before I just use (e:Mouseevent=null), I can go from Fullscreen to normal and back to fullscreen, but not to Interactive

Comment: I just ran some tests and I think I got to the root of the problem: You have to `allowFullscreenInteractive: "true"` in the HTML file for it to work.

Comment: I added that, the interactive runs if I go straight to it (normal to Interactive), but if I want to switch from fullScreen to FullScreenInteractive it won't. I'll see if I can go from Interactive to Full.

Comment: Well, that's just weird. I just tried it and it worked without issues. How are you triggering the displayState switch? Passing/defaulting to null the mouse event works for local/sandbox testing, but you won't be able to make that work in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of research, I can conclude from Adobe Evangelist, that

Normal to Full_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE is possible.
Full_SCREEN to Full_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE is NOT possible (Should be, and I don't see why not).

Answer (score 0):

for some reason you have to do this:

```
if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN)
{
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
}
```